# Is there a built-in PSTricks macro to get the value of \pslinewidth in the current unit?

Tags: pstricks

I need the value (without trailing unit) of `\pslinewidth` in `\psunit`. 
I have done as follows but I am disappointed with the accuracy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pstricks}
\pstFPdiv\Temp
{\the\pslinewidth}
{\the\psunit}

\begin{document}
\the\pslinewidth% prints 0.8pt

\Temp% prints 0.028116799998875328

\psset{linewidth=\Temp}
\the\pslinewidth% prints 0.80014pt
\end{document}
```

Is there a built-in macro to get the value (without trailing unit) of `\pslinewidth` in any `\psunit`? The value is very useful to adjust plotting domain such that the cropped curve strokes near the domain edges can be avoided.

---

The real scenario is as follows. Note: `\Temp` is the half of `\pslinewidth` that is not the same as the example above.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\def\Left{-1}
\def\Bottom{-1}
\def\Right{1}
\def\Top{1}


\psset{unit=2cm,linewidth=20pt}


%half of linewidth tickness
\pstFPdiv\Temp{\the\pslinewidth}{\the\dimexpr2\psunit\relax}

\pstFPsub\LEFT\Left\Temp
\pstFPsub\BOTTOM\Bottom\Temp
\pstFPadd\RIGHT\Right\Temp
\pstFPsub\TOP\Top\Temp

\begin{document}
\section*{Without extending the plotting domain}
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
        \psPolynomial[coeff=-1 0 2,linecolor=red]{\Left}{\Right}
\end{pspicture*}

\section*{With extending the plotting domain}
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](\LEFT,\BOTTOM)(\RIGHT,\TOP)
        \psPolynomial[coeff=-1 0 2,linecolor=red]{\Left}{\Right}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

---

I accepted Herbert's answer that implies that there is no such a built-in macro.

I also want to emphasize that

- Herbert's method is less accurate than mine.
- The length in Herbert's method cannot be passed to functions that only accept values without unit. But the value in mine can be passed to such functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\psset{unit=2cm,linewidth=20pt}
\newdimen\Left   \Left=-1\psxunit
\newdimen\Bottom \Bottom=-1\psxunit
\newdimen\Right  \Right=1\psyunit
\newdimen\Top    \Top=1\psyunit
\advance\Left   by -0.5\pslinewidth
\advance\Bottom by -0.5\pslinewidth
\advance\Right  by 0.5\pslinewidth
\advance\Top    by 0.5\pslinewidth

\begin{document}
\section*{With extending the plotting domain}
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
 \psPolynomial[coeff=-1 0 2,linecolor=red]{-1}{1}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The value of `\pslinewidth` must be in the current unit rather than in `pt`, so I can use it for adjusting plotting domain.

Comment: sure, nobody changed the linewidth, scaling is done on PostScript side

Comment: The required value (without trailing unit) of `\pslinewidth` must be in the current unit rather than in `pt`, so I can use it for adjusting plotting domain.

Comment: I will show you the real scenario. Please wait a minute.

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Please kindly see my updated question. The code might speak better than my English sentence. :-)

Comment: already done ...

Comment: There is a drawback with your method where the values cannot be passed to functions that only accept values without unit. :-)